# Why saving and loading UIImages in documents folder doesn't work properly in iOS 8+?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata, nsfilemanager

I've been trying to save and load UIImages in my app's Documents folder or preferably temp folder (so every time my app gets closed images will be deleted) but they aren't working correctly. I've tried three approaches but only the third approach works and i'm wondering what's the right way to do it? I highly appreciate any help.

```
 //First Approach, to save and load later, Doesn't work.
 //Saving the image
 NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                                  URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                   inDomains:NSUserDomainMask]
                                    lastObject];
NSString*fileDirectoryStr = [[documentsDirectoryURL path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"E1BG.png"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fileDirectoryStr];
//Saving either as Jpeg
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(finalFG) writeToFile:fileDirectoryStr atomically:YES];
//Or as PNG, because I need the transparent part to be kept transparent but non of them work.
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(finalFG, 1.0) writeToFile:fileDirectoryStr atomically:YES];
//Loading image
UIImage *loadedBGImg = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
//Returns nil

//Second approach.
//Saving the image
NSArray*pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * documentsPath = [pathArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* fileDirectoryStr = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"E1FG.png"];
//Again saving either as Jpeg
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(finalFG) writeToFile:fileDirectoryStr atomically:YES];
//Or as PNG, because I need the transparent part to be kept transparent but non of them work.
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(finalFG, 1.0) writeToFile:fileDirectoryStr atomically:YES];
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:fileDirectoryStr];
//Loading image
UIImage *loadedImg = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1]];

 //Third approach, Works but doesnt seem to be very efficient.
 NSString *tmpDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory();
 //Save
 NSString *tmpFileStrFG = [tmpDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"E1FG.png"];
 NSURL *urlFG = [NSURL URLWithString:tmpFileStrFG];
 NSData *imgDataFG = UIImagePNGRepresentation(finalFG);
 [imgDataFG writeToURL:urlFG atomically:YES];
 //Load
 UIImage *ImggFG = [UIImage imageWithData: imgDataFG];
```

Comment: You want to save and retrieve image from document directory .  it's  your question Correct ?

Comment: No i mean why the first two approaches don't work? what am I doing wrong? and Am I doing it right in the third approach to use the temp folder in my app for doing that? @MikeAlter

Comment: saving for approach two is looks good . pls check fetch url for loading image and i am not sure about approach one

Comment: The second one doesn't work at all. Can you provide an efficient way which will work with all ios updates including ios 11? @MikeAlter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created `class` which allows to save in document folder

Here is .h File

```
@interface FileUtility : NSObject {

}

// Folder methods
+ (NSString*)basePath;
+ (void)createFile:(NSString *)filename;
+ (void)createFile:(NSString *)filePath withData: (NSData *) imgData;

@end
```

and .m File

```
#import "FileUtility.h"

@implementation FileUtility

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Path methods

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

+ (NSString*)basePath {
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSAssert([paths count] == 1, @"");
    return [paths objectAtIndex:0];     
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------




  + (void)createFile:(NSString *)filename {
    NSFileManager* manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString * filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [FileUtility basePath],filename];
    DLOG(@"filePath = %@", filePath);
    if (![FileUtility fileExists:filePath]){
        [manager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    }

    }

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

+ (void)createFile:(NSString *)filePath withData: (NSData *) imgData {
    NSFileManager* manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    DLOG(@"filePath = %@", filePath);
    if (![FileUtility fileExists:filePath]){
        [manager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:imgData attributes:nil];
    }
}
```

For fetch  use this

`[[FileUtility basePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent`

**EDIT**

```
+ (BOOL)fileExists:(NSString *)filename {
    NSFileManager* manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    return [manager fileExistsAtPath:filename];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Just a quick question, If I wanted to save them in the temp folder I should use NSTemporaryDirectory() instead of NSDocumentDirectory in the base path right?

Comment: Although `Dlog` and `[FileUtility fileExists:filePath]` gives me errors. says no class method exists for `fileExists:`

Comment: @Reza.Ab  DLog is NSLog and  `fileExists:filePath` added  in Edit

Comment: In order to use temp folder I should replace NSTemporaryDirectory() with NSDocumentDirectory in the base path right? and what method from nsfilemanager i should use to load files? Im doing this to load files `+ (UIImage*)loadImageFileWithPath:(NSString*)path{
    NSData *file = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    UIImage *  loadedImg = [UIImage imageWithData:file scale:1.0];
    return loadedImg;
}` Thank you @MikeAlter

Comment: So I ended up modifying the code like this to add a method for loading image but then I get memory warnings which is exactly the opposite of the whole thing is about. I'm currently using file =[NSData initWithContentsOfFile:path]; and then getting the UIImage like myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:file scale:1.0];. I thought imageWithData would take much less memory than [UIImage imageNamed:]; @MikeAlter

Comment: @Reza.Ab Is dependent on your image size. If you are loading very large images then it definitely  increase the memory warning, and  [UIImage imageNamed:];  is used to load image from bundle However  imageWithData:file  can be used to get data from document folder of app

Answer (score 2):

before reading the file, make sure it exists there. If It does exist the the issue is in `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]` else image is not being converted to data.

I would recommend, break your code into several statement instead of of writing single lengthy statement for better understanding of where it is failing.

Comment: In the first and the second approach, fileDirectoryStr  return nil but why? they're the address which apple documentation is telling us to use. But the third approach works and its slow! What would be the most efficient and correct way to do it if they're not? @JitendraSingh

Comment: URLs are fine, I see the correct value (not nil) in both approaches.

Comment: Use FileUtility from @Mike answer. You may modify that file to make the read/write operation on separate thread (other than main thread) so that UI will not hang if you are writing a large file.

Comment: Thank you, They're just 80 small UIImages.

Comment: Did you try them in ios11 ? it still returns nill for me. @JitendraSingh