# UIImage cant save to document folder ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am trying to save uiimage to the document folder, but can't find it work with following code:

```
-(void) BtnClicked: (id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Btn clicked");
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file2.txt"];
    NSString *pngPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"test2.png"];
    NSString *str = @"hello world";
    UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
    NSData *dataImage = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(uiImage)];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
    imageView.image = uiImage;
    [self.view addSubview: imageView];
    [dataImage writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
    [str writeToFile:filePath atomically:TRUE encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

}
```

As the code showing above, I add a string to test together, I could find the `file2.txt` in the container download by Xcode but can't find the `png` file, I also add a `UIImage` view to show the image to avoid other error, and the image was successfully showed.

What has been wrong?

[image]

Comment: Your `pngPath` is looks like problematic  ,You have used  `stringByAppendingString` instead of   `stringByAppendingPathComponent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small mistake

observe both

```
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file2.txt"];
NSString *pngPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"test2.png"];
```

`stringByAppendingPathComponent` should be used at the place of  `stringByAppendingString`

Hope it will solve your problem

**EDIT**

Instead of use like this you should create a class which allows to do all operation with document folder

I already posted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45963431/4601900

Please use this class if it is relevant to